# Adding a search bar that interacts with an existing checkbox-based search filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, checkbox, filter

I have designed this search filter:
http://jsfiddle.net/n3EmN/171/
It's made with checkboxes, but I want to add a search bar too, which will interact with the checkboxes.  Can someone help me with jQuery or JavaScript code to do it?

### HTML

```
<pre id=result> </pre>

<div class="flowers-wrap">

  <h3 style="font-size:14px; font-weight:normal;">Available Flowers</h3>
  <p style="font-size:12px;"><strong>Filter flowers by colour:</strong></p>
  <form>
    <label style="font-size:12px;">
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" value="red" id="red" /> Red</label>
    <br>
    <label style="font-size:12px;">
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" value="yellow" id="yellow" /> Yellow</label>
    <br>
    <label style="font-size:12px;">
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" value="pink" id="pink" /> Pink</label>
    <br>
    <label style="font-size:12px;">
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" value="purple" id="purple" /> Purple</label>
    <br>
    <label style="font-size:12px;">
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" value="green" id="green" /> Green</label>
    <br>
    <label style="font-size:12px;">
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" value="other" id="other" /> Other</label>
  </form>
  <p style="font-size:12px;"><strong>Filter flowers by size:</strong></p>
  <form>
    <label style="font-size:12px;">
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" value="tiny" id="tiny" /> Tiny</label>
    <br>
    <label style="font-size:12px;">
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" value="small" id="small" /> Small</label>
    <br>
    <label style="font-size:12px;">
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" value="medium" id="medium" /> Medium</label>
    <br>
    <label style="font-size:12px;">
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" value="large" id="large" /> Large</label>
    <br>
    <label style="font-size:12px;">
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" value="giant" id="giant" /> Giant</label>
  </form>

</div>

<div class="continents-wrap">

  <h3 style="font-size:14px; font-weight:normal;">Available Continents</h3>

  <div class="continents" style="font-size:12px;">
    <div>Africa
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-cont" value="africa" id="africa" />
    </div>
    <div>Europe
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-cont" value="europe" id="europe" />
    </div>
    <div>Asia
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-cont" value="asia" id="asia" />
    </div>
    <div>North America
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-cont" value="north-america" id="north-america" />
    </div>
    <div>South America
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-cont" value="south-america" id="south-america" />
    </div>
    <div>Antarctica
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-cont" value="antarctica" id="antarctica" />
    </div>
    <div>Australasia
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-cont" value="australasia" id="australasia" />
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="flowers">
  <div class="flower" data-id="aloe" data-category="green small medium africa">Aloe</div>
  <div class="flower" data-id="lavendar" data-category="purple green medium africa europe">Lavender</div>
  <div class="flower" data-id="stinging-nettle" data-category="green large africa europe asia">Stinging Nettle</div>
  <div class="flower" data-id="gorse" data-category="green yellow large europe">Gorse</div>
  <div class="flower" data-id="hemp" data-category="green large asia">Hemp</div>
  <div class="flower" data-id="titan-arum" data-category="purple other giant asia">Titan Arum</div>
  <div class="flower" data-id="golden-wattle" data-category="green yellow large australasia">Golden Wattle</div>
  <div class="flower" data-id="purple-prairie-clover" data-category="purple green other medium north-america">Purple Prairie Clover</div>
  <div class="flower" data-id="camellia" data-category="pink other large north-america">Camellia</div>
  <div class="flower" data-id="scarlet-carnation" data-category="red medium north-america">Scarlet Carnation</div>
  <div class="flower" data-id="indian-paintbrush" data-category="red medium north-america">Indian Paintbrush</div>
  <div class="flower" data-id="moss-verbena" data-category="purple other small south-america">Moss Verbena</div>
  <div class="flower" data-id="climbing-dayflower" data-category="blue tiny south-america">Climbing Dayflower</div>
  <div class="flower" data-id="antarctic-pearlwort" data-category="green yellow large antarctica">Antarctic Pearlwort</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
body {
  font-family: 'Arial';
  color: #646464;
}

.continents-wrap {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 5% 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flowers-wrap {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 5% 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.flowers {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.flowers div {
  float: left;
  width: 90%;
  height: 68px;
  line-height: 68px;
  padding: 0 5%;
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0 0 1px;
  position: relative;
}
```

### JavaScript

```
var $filterCheckboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');

$filterCheckboxes.on('change', function() {

  var selectedFilters = {};

  $filterCheckboxes.filter(':checked').each(function() {

    if (!selectedFilters.hasOwnProperty(this.name)) {
      selectedFilters[this.name] = [];
    }

    selectedFilters[this.name].push(this.value);

  });

  // create a collection containing all of the filterable elements
  var $filteredResults = $('.flower');

  // loop over the selected filter name -> (array) values pairs
  $.each(selectedFilters, function(name, filterValues) {

    // filter each .flower element
    $filteredResults = $filteredResults.filter(function() {

      var matched = false,
        currentFilterValues = $(this).data('category').split(' ');

      // loop over each category value in the current .flower's data-category
      $.each(currentFilterValues, function(_, currentFilterValue) {

        // if the current category exists in the selected filters array
        // set matched to true, and stop looping. as we're ORing in each
        // set of filters, we only need to match once

        if ($.inArray(currentFilterValue, filterValues) != -1) {
          matched = true;
          return false;
        }
      });

      // if matched is true the current .flower element is returned
      return matched;

    });
  });

  $('.flower').hide().filter($filteredResults).show();



});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "searchbar"?

Comment: a bar where you can enter key words,and it will show the results,and will hide divs that doesnt fit the key words.

Comment: Similarly to your usage of the `input` checkbox element with the `change` event, you can use the `input` text element with `change` or `keyup` event to catch changes in keywords.  Filtering would be similar to your code using checkboxes.

Comment: can i have the example please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I edited your question to fix some formatting and make some of the language clearer.  However, you may find that you get a better answer to your question if you can provide some JavaScript code showing what you've tried so far to implement your search bar.  (If you just want someone to write code for you, Stack Overflow is not the best place to get that kind of help.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to search on flower names, here is something you could like:

All I did is to create an array for the flower names you have in your HTML.
Then compare the inputed characters to it using `.indexOf()`.

Notice that the comparison is made in lowercase on the flower name and on the user input.

```js
var $filterCheckboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');

$filterCheckboxes.on('change', function() {

    var selectedFilters = {};

    $filterCheckboxes.filter(':checked').each(function() {

        if (!selectedFilters.hasOwnProperty(this.name)) {
            selectedFilters[this.name] = [];
        }

        selectedFilters[this.name].push(this.value);

    });

    // create a collection containing all of the filterable elements
    var $filteredResults = $('.flower');

    // loop over the selected filter name -> (array) values pairs
    $.each(selectedFilters, function(name, filterValues) {

        // filter each .flower element
        $filteredResults = $filteredResults.filter(function() {

            var matched = false,
                currentFilterValues = $(this).data('category').split(' ');

            // loop over each category value in the current .flower's data-category
            $.each(currentFilterValues, function(_, currentFilterValue) {

                // if the current category exists in the selected filters array
                // set matched to true, and stop looping. as we're ORing in each
                // set of filters, we only need to match once

                if ($.inArray(currentFilterValue, filterValues) != -1) {
                    matched = true;
                    return false;
                }
            });

            // if matched is true the current .flower element is returned
            return matched;

        });
    });

    $('.flower').hide().filter($filteredResults).show();



});


var flowerArray = [];
$(".flower").each(function(){
    flowerArray.push($(this).html().toLowerCase());
});
//console.log(flowerArray);


$("#searchFlowerNames").on("input",function(){
    var searchInput = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("input[name='fl-colour']").attr("checked",false);
    $("input[name='fl-size']").attr("checked",false);
    $("input[name='fl-cont']").attr("checked",false);
    
    var searchInputSplit =  searchInput.split(" ");
    
    if(searchInput!=""){
        $(".flower").hide(); 
        $(".flower").each(function(){

            for(i=0;i<searchInputSplit.length;i++){
                // We have a match.
                if($(this).html().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchInputSplit[i]) != -1 && searchInputSplit[i]!=""){
                    $(this).show();

                    // To check the relevant checkboxes, have to get the category of this match.
                    var thisFlowerData = $(this).data("category").toLowerCase().split(" ");
                    //console.log(thisFlowerData);

                    // Set the flower color checkboxes
                    $("input[name='fl-colour']").each(function(){
                        if(thisFlowerData.indexOf($(this).val().toLowerCase()) != -1){
                            $(this).prop("checked",true);
                            //console.log($(this).val());
                        }
                    });

                    // Set the flower size checkboxes
                    $("input[name='fl-size']").each(function(){
                        if(thisFlowerData.indexOf($(this).val().toLowerCase()) != -1){
                            $(this).prop("checked",true);
                            //console.log($(this).val());
                        }
                    });

                    // Set the flower continent checkboxes
                    $("input[name='fl-cont']").each(function(){
                        if(thisFlowerData.indexOf($(this).val().toLowerCase()) != -1){
                            $(this).prop("checked",true);
                            //console.log($(this).val());
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }else{
        $(".flower").show(); 
    }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Arial';
  color: #646464;
}

.continents-wrap {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 5% 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flowers-wrap {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 5% 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.flowers {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.flowers div {
  float: left;
  width: 90%;
  height: 68px;
  line-height: 68px;
  padding: 0 5%;
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0 0 1px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id=result> </pre>

<input type="text" id="searchFlowerNames" placeholder="Type a flower name..."><span id="searchResult"></span>

<div class="flowers-wrap">
    

    <h3 style="font-size:14px; font-weight:normal;">Available Flowers</h3>
    <p style="font-size:12px;"><strong>Filter flowers by colour:</strong></p>
    <form>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" value="red" id="red" /> Red</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" value="yellow" id="yellow" /> Yellow</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" value="pink" id="pink" /> Pink</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" value="purple" id="purple" /> Purple</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" value="green" id="green" /> Green</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" value="other" id="other" /> Other</label>
    </form>
    <p style="font-size:12px;"><strong>Filter flowers by size:</strong></p>
    <form>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" value="tiny" id="tiny" /> Tiny</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" value="small" id="small" /> Small</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" value="medium" id="medium" /> Medium</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" value="large" id="large" /> Large</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" value="giant" id="giant" /> Giant</label>
    </form>

</div>

<div class="continents-wrap">

    <h3 style="font-size:14px; font-weight:normal;">Available Continents</h3>

    <div class="continents" style="font-size:12px;">
        <div>Africa
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-cont" value="africa" id="africa" />
        </div>
        <div>Europe
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-cont" value="europe" id="europe" />
        </div>
        <div>Asia
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-cont" value="asia" id="asia" />
        </div>
        <div>North America
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-cont" value="north-america" id="north-america" />
        </div>
        <div>South America
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-cont" value="south-america" id="south-america" />
        </div>
        <div>Antarctica
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-cont" value="antarctica" id="antarctica" />
        </div>
        <div>Australasia
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-cont" value="australasia" id="australasia" />
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="flowers">
    <div class="flower" data-id="aloe" data-category="green small medium africa">Aloe</div>
    <div class="flower" data-id="lavendar" data-category="purple green medium africa europe">Lavender</div>
    <div class="flower" data-id="stinging-nettle" data-category="green large africa europe asia">Stinging Nettle</div>
    <div class="flower" data-id="gorse" data-category="green yellow large europe">Gorse</div>
    <div class="flower" data-id="hemp" data-category="green large asia">Hemp</div>
    <div class="flower" data-id="titan-arum" data-category="purple other giant asia">Titan Arum</div>
    <div class="flower" data-id="golden-wattle" data-category="green yellow large australasia">Golden Wattle</div>
    <div class="flower" data-id="purple-prairie-clover" data-category="purple green other medium north-america">Purple Prairie Clover</div>
    <div class="flower" data-id="camellia" data-category="pink other large north-america">Camellia</div>
    <div class="flower" data-id="scarlet-carnation" data-category="red medium north-america">Scarlet Carnation</div>
    <div class="flower" data-id="indian-paintbrush" data-category="red medium north-america">Indian Paintbrush</div>
    <div class="flower" data-id="moss-verbena" data-category="purple other small south-america">Moss Verbena</div>
    <div class="flower" data-id="climbing-dayflower" data-category="blue tiny south-america">Climbing Dayflower</div>
    <div class="flower" data-id="antarctic-pearlwort" data-category="green yellow large antarctica">Antarctic Pearlwort</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah,nice one but look, i mean i have for exemple checked 1 checkbox,for exemple yellow,i have 3 results(Gorse,Golden Wattle,Antarctic Pearlwort).

Comment: how to make search bar able to find result just from those 3 results(Gorse,Golden Wattle,Antarctic Pearlwort).Because if i try to tap "Aloe" it will show "Aloe" but in checkbox "Aloe" is not checked,sorry for my english,hope you understand :)

Comment: I knew you would like to do that too... See my update ;).

Comment: Hey man,sorry for answer,you alredy helped me but i have one question,respond if you have free time.Look search works well,but why for exemple when i paste just "a" in searchbar it shows all the result,even they dont have letter "a" in,why?

Comment: Are you sure? In the snippet above, there is only 3 flowers (Stinging Nettle, Gorse and Hemp) that do not have an "a". And they don't show.

Comment: sorry my fault.

Comment: now i found a new problem that i cant resolve.If you have a bit of time check it again please. https://fiddle.jshell.net/cabeqaky/11/

Comment: look at the flower Purple Prairie Clover,if i enter Purple Prairie i will get the result,or just Purple or Prairie or Clover,but when i enter Purple Clover i cant get the result.Can you help me to solve it please?

Comment: I edited. The trick is to split the `searchInput` at every spaces into an array. Then perform the "match" check on each words. ;)